# Is it advisable to cite a lot of commecial product web references in a survey paper?

Tags: publications, citations, review-articles

I'm currently writing a survey on a specific topic in biomechanics. In one of the sections, a tabulation of tools with columns name, type, description, and study is included.

The plan was to cite the home page of the commercial product next to the tool name and cite the relevant literature that use them in the study section. This would mean 20+ product home pages in the in the reference section out of around 200 references. My intention was to allow the reader to refer the product page for more detail regarding the tool concerned.

From a reviewer's standpoint, is it a good idea to cite so many commercial product links in an academic article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a deeper thought, I've come to a conclusion not to cite commercial product pages as it would turn part of my academic paper into an online shopping catalogue.

The following are the alternatives adopted:

- Include the name of the company along with product name
- Cite patents of the products
- Cite product-specific publications